# Asp.Net Java Script to change Gridview row color based on code behind loop

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I would like to change the color of gridview1 row based the loop using Java Script.

But when I click the Upload button the loop runs without any color change.

Don't know what I am missing.

```
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    With GridView1
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count - 1
            btnUpload.Attributes.Add("onClick", "ChangeColor('" + "GridView1','" + (i).ToString() + "')")
        Next
    End With
End Sub



<script type="text/javascript">
        function ChangeColor(GridViewId, SelectedRowId) {
            var GridViewControl = document.getElementById(GridViewId);
            if (GridViewControl != null) {
                var GridViewRows = GridViewControl.rows;
                if (GridViewRows != null)
                {
                    var SelectedRow = GridViewRows[SelectedRowId];
                    //Remove Selected Row color if any
                    for (var i = 1; i < GridViewRows.length; i++) {
                        var row = GridViewRows[i];
                        if (row == SelectedRow) {
                            //Apply Yellow color to selected Row
                            row.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffda";
                        }
                        else {
                            //Apply White color to rest of rows
                            row.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
                        }
                }

                }
            }

        }
</script>
```

Comment: The button click of `btnUpload` will probably trigger a PostBack, so any changes made to the GridView with javascript are lost.

Comment: Then how to achieve this? I just want to show which row is in process by way of highlighting the row.

Comment: You can color the row, but the color is lost very fast so you only get a blinking effect at most.

Comment: I know but the code will interact with SQL server for updating the records so it will run slowly I think.

Comment: Note that the [tag:visual-studio] tag description says *"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."* Please [edit] your question to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I have removed VS tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. There is no need for attaching an OnClick in the OnRowDataBound event. This assumes that the upload button is a Button, not a LinkButton. But you can modify the script easily.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', '#00ff00');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I don't find gridview row number (comes from loop) in the above JS.  Please correct me if I am missing anything.

Comment: You don't need it. The script finds the `<tr>` of the button that was clicked and colors it.

Comment: But nothing going to be clicked by the user.  Since I just going to loop the Gridview row cells and I insert the data in SQL Server.  So there will not be any selection process will happen in code.

Comment: Ah, that is what you mean. That won't work at all what you want. The UI does not get updated until all backed code is done (all files have been processed). If you want row by row updates you need to post files with Ajax to an API and process them one by one.

Comment: Seems like a tedious process :(